# Copying/Exporting a 1D or a 2D array in python to an excel file?

Tags: python, arrays, excel

I have a couple of 1D arrays and a 2D array, that I want to view in an excel file. I am generating and manipulating these arrays in python but I want to view them finally in an excel file.

Is there a way I can just export the arrays to excel, rather than copying these arrays element by element using xlsxwriter, [like they've shown it here](https://biokamikazi.wordpress.com/2016/07/07/export-numpy-array-to-excel-in-python/)?

Comment: You could store these arrays as a `DataFrame` using `pandas` and then use `to_excel()` method to save them as an excel file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution could be using the `pandas` package and then creating a CSV.

```
import pandas
dataframe_array= pandas.DataFrame(your_array)
dataframe_array.to_csv(your_path)
```

and then just view the `csv` in excel

Comment: Thanks. Do I need to import any specific library before I can do that ?

Comment: Yes, pandas is the library you would need. It is a really good data handling library for python. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18/index.html

Comment: Could you help me with the to_csv(your_path) part of the code? basically I am writing it as 
df.to_csv(wav.xlsx), where wav is the excel file i want the array to go to, and its in the same folder as my code file. The code throws an error saying that ' name wav is not defined'

Comment: Yeah sure. So using the `to_csv` command it is expecting you to write the file as a csv not an xlsx. Excel can easily open a CSV file however. so it should look something like:
`df.to_csv('C:/My Documents/test.csv')`
For an xlsx it is slightly more complicated:

`write_excel= pd.ExcelWriter('C:/My Documents.test.xlsx', engine = 'xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(write_excel, sheet_name='my_sheet' , index=False)`

Comment: Ah, got it. Thanks a ton :)

Answer (score 1):

I would agree with the above as the trick is to use pandas.  My example below shows the creation of an excel file with each array in a different sheet.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# create two 1 D arrays
A1d1 = np.full((5),fill_value=1)
B1d2 = np.full((5),fill_value=2)
# create one 2 D array 
C2d3 = np.full((5,5),fill_value=3)

# convert to pandas DataFrames
A1d1_df = pd.DataFrame(A1d1)
B1d2_df = pd.DataFrame(B1d2)
C2d3_df = pd.DataFrame(C2d3)

# Use pandas Excel Writer to create one Excel file with
# a sheet for each array
with pd.ExcelWriter('yourexcelfile.xlsx') as writer:
    A1d1_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='A1d1')
    B1d2_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='B1d2')
    C2d3_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='C2d3')
```